# Inserting Google MD icons into Fullcalendar Event

Tags: javascript, php, css, fullcalendar

I have started using the fullcalendar plugin for a calendar display of mine.
The goal of the calendar is to allow the user to add events labled Accommodation or Canteen.

When my page loads, I use PHP to build an array that gets parsed to the JavaScript that displays the events.

What I would like to do is be able to display the Google Material Design icons with the matching event.

Accommodation will be the hotel icon.

Canteen will be the local dining icon.

Now in Google's [documentation](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/) it shows that the icons can be applied using the following method:

`<i class="material-icons">hotel</i>`

However when passing events to the plugin, this does not seem to be possible.

The php where the array gets built:

```
$events = array();
while (!$result->eof()) {
    if ($result->valueof('date_canteen_available') == 't') {


        $events[] = array("title" => "Canteen", "start" => $result->valueof('date_date'));
    }
    if ($result->valueof('date_accommodation_available') == 't') {
        $events[] = array("title" => "Accommodation", "start" => $result->valueof('date_date'));
    }
```

Part of my javascript:

```
<script>
    $('#calendarAccomo').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                },
                defaultView: 'month',
                editable: true,
                selectable: true,
                allDaySlot: false,
                events: <?php echo json_encode($events) ?>,
</script>
```

My question is, how can I display the correct icon with each event entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: [{
    title: 'Accommodation',
    start: '2017-02-01',
    description: 'This is a cool event'
  }, {
    title: 'Canteen',
    start: '2017-02-02',
    description: 'This is a cool event'
  }],
  eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    if (event.title == 'Accommodation') {
      element.append('<i class="material-icons">hotel</i>');
    } else {
      element.append('<i class="material-icons">local_dining</i>');
    }
  }
});
```

Try the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/61vwsq10/).